# collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Tags: c++, c, gcc, mingw, collect

Please I need help when I try to compile my .C to png

```
gcc --std=c99 -Wall -lz a.c -o a.png
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.8.1/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lz
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

What does this mean?

Comment: Do you have a `zip` library installed on your machine?

Comment: No, or I am going to place him(it) in Windows with mingw

Comment: Read what the `-l` option does in `gcc`: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Link-Options.html#Link-Options. It's telling you that it can't find that library. You need to have it installed where your compiler will look for it and that depends on your setup.

Comment: Also, in [this SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6658194/1667513) it mentions that **collect2.exe** is being used to simply invoke the linker.

Comment: `gcc --std=c99 -Wall -L/lib -lz a.c -o a.png`

Comment: gcc --std=c99 -Wall -L/lib -lz a.c -o a.png  doesn't work

Comment: I was always taught that the library selection(s) '-lz' had to be last, so they can resolve external references produced by the user code 'a.c'

Comment: Compile C code to png? What does it even mean? Anyway, you don't have zlib, that's what linker saying. Install it with e.g. `mingw-get install zlib`.

Comment: Why `-o a.png`?

Answer (score 0):

From the error message, the linker says that it can not find `libz.so` or `libz.a`.
If you are providing that lib from your own path,
tell the linker that it has to search in your path, by

```
gcc --std=c99 -Wall -Ldir -lz a.c -o a.png
```

use

```
ld -lz --verbose
```

to see where linker has searched for libz.